Cannot Unmarshel metro config file jaxws-rt-4.0.3.jar/META-INF/jaxws-tubes-default.xml
I am migrating a cmis project from jdk1.8 to jdk17 (using jboss8),
as javax is no longer supported, I have changed the corresponding dependencies to jakarta, and upgraded jaxws-rt-2.3.jar to jaxws-rt-4.0.3.jar compile time errors are resolved but at runtime getting errors

Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.InternalError: MASM0010: Unable to unmarshall metro config file from location [ vfs:/D:/OD12July/jboss-eap-8.0.0/jboss-eap-8.0/bin/content/omnidocscmis.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-4.0.3.jar/META-INF/jaxws-tubes-default.xml ]"}}"

I also have added jaxb dependencies such as jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar, jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar, jaxb-impl-4.0.5.jar, jaxb-runtime-4.0.5.jar

If you're targeting jakarta, why include jaxb-api 2.x ? You should take jaxb-api 4.0 since already getting the jaxb-runtime 4.0.5 (beware not to include same class twice with runtime / core / impl jaxb jars).
